# How to remove unwanted characters (brackets) from pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

One of the column values in my csv file contains unwanted characters (`"'`). I've tried to remove them by using the below method, but it won't let me:

```
df= df.replace({'"'':''}, regex=True)
```

Could someone please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: `df.replace('"', '', regex=True)`?

Comment: Hi Quang, but I'm trying to remove `"'` not `"`

Comment: `df.replace('"\'', '', regex=True)`, notice the escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Try remove them one by one

```
df = df.replace({'"':''}, regex=True).replace({"'":''}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Or `df.replace({'"|\'':''}, regex=True)`